# Changing font of the browser tab in React App

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts

Does anyone out there in the universe know how to change the font family for the app title that appears in the tab of your web browser? Like the one shown below

[image]

I know in the index.html file in the public folder there is the `<title>React App</title>` where you can change the title, but I'm not sure how to change the font.

Thanks in advance!
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You asked very good questions, in fact you can't change it. Simply go to your console. Do this :
const title = document.getElementByTagName('title');
Then press enter. After that simply write again the console:
title.
And you will see the html collection for the tag title. If you keep looking you will see a lot of options are null. Do you will understand that the tag title it's can't be modified as much as the other tags like h1 or span. You can add a javascript code to update the title let's say the number of notifications along side the title so you can do this :
document.title= (3) + is "react app".
Hope I answered your question .
Ps: I'm using my phone sorry to not provide the codes in there specific area.